# (Reference Request) Simplicial Complexes and Homology Book

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology, book-recommendation, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

A student has asked for references on simplicial complexes, and I remember a book but can't find its name.  Pretty sure it was a yellow Springer book, but not sure what series - and I'm not even 100% sure about that.

What I remember about it is that it's the easiest book by far for simplicial complexes while also managing to cover most of the main theorems.  The book started either immediately or almost immediately with them - and it wasn't Spanier, it was a very easy book that also happened to be pretty rigorous (tho I think they left out a proof here or there).  It doesn't just blow past them in a few pages to race straight to homology.

The most interesting aspect of it was that after they did all the simplicial complex background, they started out on homology but devoted an entire chapter to graphs.  I recall this as being very easy to digest and helpful in building intuition, so I wanted to recommend this book but just can't find it!

It's not any of the Massey books, either.  It may not even have "algebraic topology" in the title; could've been something on PL manifolds, or similar.

Does this sound familiar to anybody?  I think the book was kind of on the shorter side, like <300 pages.

Comment: For some reason I thought the name of the author was something similar to Spanier, tho.  But in what sense it was 'similar' I don't know haha, it might just also be short.

Comment: Googling a bit, would [Giblin](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Graphs_Surfaces_and_Homology/8dez6ToQj2QC?hl=en&gbpv=0) fit the bill? It doesn't quite fit your description, unfortunately: it does graphs first, then simplicial complexes, then homology.

Comment: Yup, that's the one I was looking for.  I had checked the 2nd edition which is quite different, but the 3rd edition is the book I remembered!